# Can you add a cookie to request with asp.net core middleware?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, request, session-cookies, middleware

Am trying to write custom middleware in the ASP.net core pipeline, as part of my invoke, would like to append/add cookie, so then next middleware in the pipeline can access those cookie.

getting compiling error on set the cookie value. Can anyone recommend work around for this.

Note: When I tried with Response.Cookie , it works but only problem is, cookie is reflecting only on next request from the browser, but I need this to be reflecting on the next middleware in the pipeline immediately after execute this.

below code snippet

```
  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {


            var queryParameters = httpContext.Request.Query;
            var cookies = httpContext.Request.Cookies;
            if (!cookies.ContainsKey(".AspNetCore.Session")
                || cookies[".AspNetCore.Session"] != "new_key")
            {
```

> httpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Session"] = "new_key";

```
            }


            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use cookie's value in same request. However, you could use good old `HttpContext.Items`.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Request.HttpContext.Items["key"] = "Hello!";
    await _next(context);
}
```

You then retrieve it as

```
var value = HttpContext.Items["key"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response...  in my case i need to modify my asp.net core session cookie... so then in the rest of the pipeline it will take care automatically.... this is has been achieved in our project using asp.net modules .... where we can modify the request cookie. Here we are trying to migrate to asp.net core hence struggle on on set request cookie

Comment: It seems that changing the RequestCookieCollection's value in middleware is impossible without modifiying ASP.net Core's source code. My workaround is quite similar to Win's. I often use the headers like this: context.Request.Headers["headerkey"] = "headervalue"; then retrieve them like this: Request.Headers["headerkey"]

Comment: Thanks Win and Guogangj. I can understand your solutions on using Headers or Items for passing the values. Actually we are trying to modify the session cookie which has been created by the Asp.net core to maintain & recognise the browser's session. This feature of modify the Request cookie is available in Asp.net, hence I was looking for the same. From your answers it is clear that we can't modify the request cookie. I need to look for different approach than modify the cookie. Once again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have an `AuthorizationHandler` that performs some checks to determine the user details and whether the user is logged in. The auth handler stores some of this info in a token in the request headers, so it can be easily accessed by the controllers.

When the user is logged in, this token can be read from the `HttpContext.Request.Headers` in a standard controller and all is well.

When the user is not logged in, the auth handler returns failure and so the request is redirected to "/login". Sadly the token header is not preserved across the redirect, so in my `LoginController` the token is null.

The only way I could make the token available to both a standard controller and `LoginController` is to store the token in both the **request headers** AND **response cookies**. This cookie can be read from the `LoginController` in the `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` collection. I set it to be short-lived as it's only needed briefly (it'll disappear after 5 seconds)

Here is part of the code from my auth handler:

```
  HttpRequest request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
  HttpResponse response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;

  request.Headers["X-Token"] = encryptedToken;
  response.Cookies.Append("TokenCookie", encryptedToken, new CookieOptions
    {
        MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        Secure = true,
        IsEssential = true,
    });
```